# Need Help regarding this Peak to Peak Detector Circuit

Tags: ac, detector

[image: Peak To Peak Detector Circuit]

Hey guys need some help from you...

I have made a small circuit (Peak to Peak Detector Circuit).  but i am confused what should be the voltage ratings of the capacitors and wattage ratings of the resistors.  Maximum AC voltage will be 550V AC.

When i supply 550 V AC, the DC output is about 800V

Comment: I'm a little concerned that you're asking novice questions like this when dealing with voltages that high. I'd like to help, but I'm concerned for your safety.

Comment: Dont worry about my safety...i am taking all the precautions.

Comment: I think @DanLaks ' comment is meant to identify exactly that if you are not fully comfortable with Ohm's law, you may very likely not know about all the precautions to go through.

Comment: Use a transformer for *galvanic separation* and reducing voltages to more reasonable levels. I don't feel comfortable where this question is going to without the use of a decent transformer. For 800V you don't need so much high power resistors, but resistors that can withstand the high voltage and serious other precautions.

Comment: Cannot use a transformer. The client has strictly restricted me from using a transformer.

Comment: What is the reason for restricting use of a transformer? I'd say he is outsourcing this project because he doesn't have sufficient knowledge himself, so why is he making restrictions like this?

Comment: @GursahibSingh: How do you know all the necessary precautions, but not ohms law?

Comment: The help I can give is to advise you that you need to give your "client" his money back and go back to school before you kill yourself or, worse, someone else.  If you think that's harsh, then I suggest that you look at the [10BQ015](http://www.vishay.com/docs/93349/10bq015m.pdf) data sheet with the realization that there'll be about 1550 volts across it on the mains' negative peaks.

Comment: That's not a peak to peak detector, just a peak detector.  If you can't even get that right, you have no business taking money for electrical design, *especially* when a mistake can cause serious injury.

Comment: @jippie: The reason for not using a transformer is that he's fixated on doing it this way, is going to do it this way regardless of what we say, so is inventing artificial constraints to force the solution be what he wants it to be.

Comment: This question should be closed.

Comment: Hi, atleast you guys can suggest me some other circuit if it is so dangerous. I m new to such high electrical voltages. My domain is Micrcontroller Design. I need to measure 500 Max AC voltage using Microcontroller

Answer (score 4):

All of the comments so far are on the money. With all due respect, you have too little knowledge to be fooling around with this level of possible damage. If you really do have a "client" who is presumably paying you money to do this, you are taking his money on false pretenses, and the results of your efforts are going to be passed along to somebody else who may be injured or killed. Just stop.

Also, of course, you have presented a wildly inaccurate schematic. Your D1 and C2 are most certainly not the components you're using, and if R1 and C1 are accurate they demonstrate that you are simply out of your depth. I will not go into more detail about why this is so, since I'm not going to encourage you.

Please. Just stop this and go do some studying about basic electronics, or at least more advanced than you already have.

Answer (score 0):

In this application note there are some precaution advice and other information about what you are going to do. Be careful about what you are doing, the circuit is not isolated and can hurt you. You should be aware that even low voltage in micro's side can hurt you due to lack of isolation.

- [AVR182: Zero Cross Detector](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2508.pdf)